# How to pass object array from PHP to JS?

Tags: javascript, php

I have table of invoices where each invoice has multiple expense row with different values. I store invoices and expenses in seperate db tables. I display all the invoices inside table on main page and I allow user to check checkboxes and each time they check it, correlated row of invoice gets pusshed into the array as an object. So I get somethnig like this

```
[{
    "id": 587,
    "name": "Ornek",
    "cariKodu": "129896",
    "adres": "HACI HALIL MAH. KIZILAY CAD. NO:29/B\nGEBZE / KOCAELI",
    "il": "ILYASBEY",
    "ilce": "Gebze"
}, {
    "id": 589,
    "name": "Ornek_1",
    "cariKodu": "34324",
    "adres": "Ataşehir Konakları",
    "il": "İstanbul",
    "ilce": "Araşehir"
}]
```

What I want is to make an array like this with expenses and push it into the array above. But I list invoices and expenses in two different pages so I don't know how to send data between those pages. I want to have one super array where each index of it is an object and inside that object I is another array of objects.

I know it's little complicated but I tried my best to explain it.

Comment: So you want to store a value, so that it “survives” navigation between different pages. Then you should either store it client-side in local- or sessionStorage, or server-side, in the session. (Which one might be more appropriate, depends on specifics - which this question so far doesn’t really provide.)

Comment: `$_SESSION` looks like a valid option for that.

Comment: @04FS Even if I store it in session variable, can I get the values from server side to client? And is it the effective way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply "pass" the JSON via pages by using `$_SESSION` both as server and client-side variable:

**page1.php** (sender)

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $json = '[{
        "id": 587,
        "name": "Ornek",
        "cariKodu": "129896",
        "adres": "HACI HALIL MAH. KIZILAY CAD. NO:29/B\nGEBZE / KOCAELI",
        "il": "ILYASBEY",
        "ilce": "Gebze"
    }, {
        "id": 589,
        "name": "Ornek_1",
        "cariKodu": "34324",
        "adres": "Ataşehir Konakları",
        "il": "İstanbul",
        "ilce": "Araşehir"
    }]';

    //convert JSON object for further use if needed
    $phpArray = json_decode($json, true);

    //save the JSON as SESSION var
    $_SESSION['json_object'] = $json;
?>
```

**page2.php** (consumer)

```
<?php
    session_start();

    //get the JSON object from the session and convert it to array for further use
    $phpArray = json_decode($_SESSION['json_object'], true);
?>
<script>
    //push JSON object into your JS
    var jsonObject = <?php echo $_SESSION['json_object']; ?>;
    console.log(jsonObject);
</script>
```

Of course, you have to implement checks for this `$_SESSION` existence in your script in order to prevent any errors, this gives you just the basic idea.